# Using CakePHP on apache tomcat server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, tomcat

I have 2 platform for single application, one is in jsp and another is in php (I am using CakePHP).

**What I want to do ?**

Now we want to share session between two platform, in that case we need to use single web platform that can deploy php and jsp webpage.

**What is the issue?**

Now the issue is `.htaccess` file is not working on apache tomcat server, so we are not able to use CakePHP. Is there any way to use Using CakePHP on apache tomcat server ?

I found this 
http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ can solve my problem ? If yes how ?

My `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks In Advance

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php

For Session, I think the best manner is serializing the session variables somewhere (for instance, an XML or YAML file). These are two different languages and the Session variables are stored in memory, not accesible between processes.

Comment: Thanks, I am using php-java bridge, can you please give me useful link or idea to share session using xml or yaml ?

Comment: PEAR has XML_Serializer that serializes variables in XML ([link](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/redirected)). You can store this XML in a common folder, readable by JSP. For Java, use a XML parser, like SAX or DOM.

Comment: Analogously, for YAML the process is the same. PHP has YAML implemented as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php). For Java use [Jyaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/).